# Bind tablix with a single row of out of many rows returned by dataset in SSRS 2008?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am fully aware that ideally, dataset should return only relevant rows with which to bind tablix.
However, in this particular case, I am utilizing same dataset to bind multiple tables and need to perform some filtering 'on the fly'.
I  tried writing logic in column visibility of each cell to achieve desired output but there is no unique condition available on cell level .
I need to  bind only single row from the dataset based on my unique column value, any pointers will be highly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't provided any code/data samples but may be you can utilize row visibility property to filter rows from dataset with which to bind individual tables as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53730)